# json parsing and storing in an arraylist in Phonegap

Tags: android, json, arraylist, cordova

in my app when the user clicks a button, it hits an url and i use to get a return data in json format as follows

```
{
  "Status":
        {
            "image":
            [ 
                { 
                    "Large" : "http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/images/original/1316145577.jpg", 
                    "Small" : "http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/images/thumb70/1316145577.jpg" 
                }, 
                {   "Large" : "http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/images/original/1316146270.jpg", 
                    "Small" : "http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/images/thumb70/1316146270.jpg" 
                }, 
                {   "Large" : "http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/images/original/1316146473.jpg", 
                    "Small" : "http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/images/thumb70/1316146473.jpg" 
                }, 
                {   "Large" : "http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/images/original/1316147003.jpg", 
                    "Small" : "http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/images/thumb70/1316147003.jpg" 
                }, 
                {   "Large" : "http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/images/original/1316581422.jpg", 
                    "Small" : "http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/images/thumb70/1316581422.jpg" 
                }, 
                {   "Large" : "http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/images/original/1316694587.jpg", 
                    "Small" : "http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/images/thumb70/1316694587.jpg" 
                } 
            ]
        }
}
```

i want to do json parsing and store the URLs named under Large to be stored in an Array and URLs named under Small to be stored in another array. I want this to be done using `javascript`.

For example in my app in another url my json data is to be as follows

```
{"Status":[{ "Id": "46", "Username": "guru" }]}
```

For this i use to get the data as

```
var data = JSON.parse(my_JSON_object);

var id = data.Status[0].Id;
var name = data.Status[0].Username;
```

But how to parse for the json array mentioned first.
How to do this, pls help me friends

Comment: I would insist to create a getter-setter class and use am ArrayList<Class> to save the urls....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer by this way

```
var data = JSON.parse(my_JSON_object);

                    var image = [];
                    for(var i=0; i< image.length(); i++)
                    {   
                        image[i] = data.Status.image[0].Large;
                        alert(image);
                    }
                        alert(image);
```